# Generating a list of delimited numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a function in Excel which is able to generate a list of numbers like this:

```
1|2|3|4|5
```

as shown in the image below:

[image]

I would like to be able to provide the start and end, something like `=NUMBERSRANGE(1,50)`. There is no need to take the input from two other cells.

I did some research and here is my first Excel function:

```
Function RANGENUMBERS(D7, E7)
For i = D7 To E7
    RANGENUMBERS = i & "|"
Next
End Function
```

How would I go and concatenate number from For loop in order to get desired result?

Comment: You mean like this `="1|2|3|4|5"`. Your question does not have enough detail. Will it always be 1-5? Do you want to provide a start and end? Will the start and end come from two other cells? Will it take a range of cells and concatenate them with pipe delimiters?

Comment: @EBGreen Oh sorry. Yes, I would like to be able to provide start and end, something like =NUMBERSRANGE(1,50), there is no need to take input from two other cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires the `TEXTJOIN()` function:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,ROW(INDEX(C:C,1):INDEX(C:C,5)))}
```

While this works as is, it is preferable to replace `C:C` with the column that the formula is entered in. That way the formula won't break if column `C` is deleted.

Note that `TEXTJOIN()` is only available in Excel 2016. In earlier versions of Excel, a poly-fill UDF is required. (See [this post](//superuser.com/a/1331555) for a basic one.)

Also note that this is a better solution than the ubiquitous alternative that uses the `INDIRECT()` function,

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,ROW(INDIRECT("1:5")))}
```

as `INDIRECT()` is volatile and causes the worksheet to calculate slower.

It is also easier to modify the `INDEX` version so the endpoints are references instead of hard-coded values.

Comment: Cannot get this to work. I'm using Excel on Mac, version 15. All I get is text as formula, there is no range of numbers.

Comment: @RhymeGuy Oops! Forgot to mention that you need to remove the `{` and `}` from the formula. They are just there to remind you to array enter the formula as opposed to normally entering it. If you don't (as you didn't) you will just get the formula as text.

Comment: @robinCTS, how to work with earlier versions since TEXTJOIN works only with 2016 !

Answer (score 0):

Similar to telephone number and zip+4 masking, if the number will always be 5 digits, then how about using a custom number format like: #|#|#|#|#

Comment: Please read [the OP's comment](//superuser.com/q/1336230/#comment1998650_1336230) on the question. *Clearly* it will  not always be five digits, so this answer is not applicable.

Comment: Good trick otherwise.